# List view should not automatically be created when queue is created

Tags: list-view, queue

When I create a queue, a list view is automatically created. I don't need these list views and it is quite annoying to delete them. Is there a possiblity that these list views are not automatically created or is there any workaround?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Winter 17 release) this is not possible for most objects, anytime a new queue is created a new list view will also be created with permissions for all user types to see it. There are exceptions for the [Order object](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000240942&language=en_US) where it is not created by default.

Developer documentation [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm):

> When you create a queue, a corresponding list view is automatically created

There is this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Ir5rAAC) for it to be restricted to the admin creating it or giving a warning on creation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to delete list views in Apex? I always get the error: System.TypeException: DML operation DELETE not allowed on ListView

Comment: I'm going to guess that exception confirms that it is not possible to use Apex to delete the ListViews. I've not tried to myself so haven't encountered that error yet.